# Javascript reset a loop until max number of elements on page reached

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around trying to learn more Javascript and I have a json list of images (for now just placeholders) and I'm replacing the `img` `src` of all images on the page with the src from the json file.

My problem is that when I hit the 4 image sources listed in the json file, the script stops. What I need to do is reset the script to continue from the start again until all images have their src changed...

JS:

```
var fogle_booth = [{
        "name": "Fogle in trunks",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/350x150"
    }, {
        "name": "Fogles does fishing",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/450x150"
    }, {
        "name": "We love fogle",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/550x150"
    }, {
        "name": "Fogle goes walking",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/650x150"
}];


for(var i = 0; i < fogle_booth.length; i++) {

    var obj = fogle_booth[i];
    var image_src = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    image_src[i].setAttribute("src",(obj.image));
    console.log(obj.image);

    if(image_src.length > obj.length) {
        console.log("resetting");
        continue;
    }
}
```

I attempted something (which could be miles off) - but I think I may be using the if statement hugely wrong.

Say there is 10 images on the page like:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" />
```

I need to be able to reset the loop until all 10 images have their src changed. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: i am not clear on what you want to do? what do you mean by "reset the script"?

Comment: So you want to replace `img src` with your script above. Shouldn't you array contains at least 10 entries as you have 10 `<img>` tags?

Comment: @D4V1D That's what I was trying to say. If my list contains 4 yet there are 10 on the page - can I make it loop through the JSON again until all images are changed?

Comment: Okay, working on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// get the list of images first
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

// set a counter
var count = 0;

// loop through the image nodelist
for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++) {

    // use count to grab the object from the array
    var obj = fogle_booth[count];

    // set your image source to be the value of the image name in your object
    imgs[i].src = obj.image;

    // increase the count
    // if it hits the length of the array, reset count
    count++;
    if (count === fogle_booth.length - 1) count = 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/v2u77bgw/4/)

Comment: This feels nice because I essentially wouldn't need to explicitly set a max count for the JSON objects - meaning if my JSON had more over time I wouldn't need to change anything else from what I can see!

Comment: Note, I just edited my answer because the check was incorrect. The demo reflects that.

Comment: For future note and anyone looking at this question for a similar reason - I'm accepting this becaues it feels clean and simple.

Answer (score 3):

Revised to take into account the length of your JSON and use ternary operator to save space

You want you for loop to run on the number of images, not the number of items in your JSON.  Then, use a separate variable to count through your JSON array and reset when it has hit 3 (i.e. 4 items total).

```
var img_counter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {

    var obj = fogle_booth[img_counter];
    var image_src = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    image_src[i].setAttribute("src",(obj.image));

    img_counter++;
    img_counter = (img_counter == fogle_booth.length) ? 0 : img_counter;

}
```

You can view the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2cfhf3s/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way

```
    <script>
var fogle_booth = [{
        "name": "Fogle in trunks",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/350x150"
    }, {
        "name": "Fogles does fishing",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/450x150"
    }, {
        "name": "We love fogle",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/550x150"
    }, {
        "name": "Fogle goes walking",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/650x150"
}];

   var image_src = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var curr_img=0,count=image_src.length;
for(var i = 0; i < fogle_booth.length; i++) {
    if(curr_img<count){
    var obj = fogle_booth[i];
    image_src[curr_img++].setAttribute("src",(obj.image));
    console.log(obj.image);
    if(i==fogle_booth.length-1)
    i=-1;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fogle_booth = [{
        "name": "Fogle in trunks",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/350x150"
    }, {
        "name": "Fogles does fishing",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/450x150"
    }, {
        "name": "We love fogle",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/550x150"
    }, {
        "name": "Fogle goes walking",
        "image": "http://placehold.it/650x150"
}];

var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img").length;

while (images > 0) {
  var rest = fogle_booth.length > images ? images : fogle_booth.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < rest; i++) {
    var obj = fogle_booth[i];
    var image_src = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    image_src[images-1].setAttribute("src",(obj.image));
    console.log(obj.image);
    images--;
 }
}
```

```html
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
<img></img>
```